# How to assign/set values to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

How to assign values to HTML element?

Below is my code,

```
If(USERROLE=="DEFAULT")
{
  //Retrive <TD>data and assign to "currentOwnerId" field of HTML
} else {
  //Get data from inputbox  id="currentOwnerId" 
}
 var currentOwner='';
 var UserRoleId=document.getElementById('UserRoleId').value;
 if(UserRoleId==='DEFAULT') {
    alert("DEFAULT USER");
    var tdElem = document.getElementById ( "currentOwnerId" );
    var tdText = tdElem.innerHTML;
    alert(tdText);
    document.getElementById('CurrentMarketOwner').innerHTML =tdText;
 } else {
    currentOwner=document.getElementById('CurrentMarketOwner').value;   
 }

 alert("Current Owner : "+currentOwner);
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Not able to assign tdText to document.getElementById('CurrentMarketOwner') value

Comment: Can you show the HTML you are using?

Comment: show the ('CurrentMarketOwner')  tag html code ..please

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use value property of JavaScript as you want to assign `tdText` value in to `CurrentMarketOwner` so please try below code may it helps you. please replace yor this line of code with below i have given.

```
document.getElementById('CurrentMarketOwner').innerHTML =tdText;
```

Replace above code with below code.

```
document.getElementById('CurrentMarketOwner').value =tdText;
```

here i have used value property to assign value in element. This will help you.